# How to use results in output directory in producing environment?

Tags: facebook, huggingface-transformers, training-data, large-language-model

I have trained `facebook/opt-6.7b` with `[BELLE][1]`'s dataset, however the biggest file `optimizer.pt` in `qlora/output/checkpoint` is only 1.1GB, and size of the whole `facebook/opt-6.7b` is about 13GB.
so where is the real model and how to use it in producing environment?

[image: 图片]

```
Saving PEFT checkpoint...
{'train_runtime': 192080.4332, 'train_samples_per_second': 0.833, 'train_steps_per_second': 0.052, 'train_loss': 1.4094205943107605, 'epoch': 0.19}               
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10000/10000 [53:21:20<00:00, 19.21s/it]
Saving PEFT checkpoint...
***** train metrics *****
  epoch                    =               0.19
  train_loss               =             1.4094
  train_runtime            = 2 days, 5:21:20.43
  train_samples_per_second =              0.833
  train_steps_per_second   =              0.052
```